# Encrypt data in Android with a RSA public.pem file generated in Ruby

Tags: android, ruby, encryption, public-key, pem

sorry to ask a particular question, but I need to generate in java code a 'signature' like the following code line in ruby:

*`signature = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("PUBLIC_PEM_PATH")).public_encrypt('SECRET_KEY')`*

I have the .pem key file and the SECRET_KEY that's is something like: *F6qxlwQTYWRM3gRfgftryKJHKYZiGXdoy5lDm4*

How can I do this ?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**
I tried this :

```
File pubKeyFile = new File(keyFileName);
    DataInputStream inputStream;
    byte[] signature = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pubKeyFile));
        byte[] pubKeyBytes = new byte[(int)pubKeyFile.length()];
        inputStream.readFully(pubKeyBytes);
        inputStream.close();

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec pubSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKeyBytes);
        RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        signature = cipher.doFinal(secretKey.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return signature;
```

And got this error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
```

**UPDATE2** 
I managed to load a public key from a .pem file. But now, Im getting an error from the cipher.

```
public static byte[] getSignature(String keyFileName, byte[] secretKey){
    byte[] signature = null;
    try {
        PublicKey pubKey = readKeyFromFile(keyFileName);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        signature = cipher.doFinal(secretKey);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return signature;
}
private static PublicKey readKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(keyFileName);
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
    try {
        BigInteger m = BigInteger.valueOf(din.readLong());
        BigInteger e = BigInteger.valueOf(din.readLong());
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
        return pubKey;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
    } finally {
        din.close();
    }
}
```

The error log:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: input must be under 8 bytes
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: Use the Signature class.

Comment: This does not look like a signature scheme. What are your requirements?

Comment: What you mean by "requirements" ? I just wanna to generate that `signature` in Java.

Comment: You generate signatures using a private key and the `Signature` class...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So finally, after hours of research I came with a solution and finally could get read my public key from .pem file and generate an instance of this key. Hence, I managed to encrypt the data.

But I had to copy and paste the *key content* without any special character like '\n' and make a `publicKeyString` with it

----------BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY---------

*key content*

----------END RSA PUBLIC KEY---------

```
static public PublicKey publicKey(String publicKeyString) {
    try {
        byte[] decodedPublicKey = Base64.decode(publicKeyString, 0);
        ASN1InputStream in = new ASN1InputStream(decodedPublicKey);
        ASN1Primitive obj = in.readObject();
        RSAPublicKeyStructure keyStruct = RSAPublicKeyStructure.getInstance(obj);
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(keyStruct.getModulus(), keyStruct.getPublicExponent());
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I failed even when I tried to use PEMReader from bouncy castle. All the problems have something to do with keys generated in Ruby version prior 1.9.3 as described with details [here](http://skim.la/2012/01/16/rsa-public-key-interoperability-between-ruby-and-android/).

Anyway, thanks a lot for the attention disposed.

Comment: Thanks for getting back with the solution, rferraz (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like key wrapping (encryption) to me. Use bouncy castle to read the PEM file, then use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")` to encrypt the secret key, and base 64 encode the result... You could also try the mode `Cipher.WRAP_MODE` to see if that works. Note that encryption will always return a different result, the only way to test for compatibility is to decrypt it with the other software.

Comment: Would you mind give more details about this process ?? I could understand a little but still have doubts about the implementation that you suggested. Also, I would like to avoid using third part libs if possible.

thaks

Comment: About the second question, if you have PEM then you need either to decode the data contained in the PEM yourself or you must use a third party lib as the functionality is not (officially) included in the Java API. It is probably somewhere in the Sun implementations, but you should definitely not use them unless you want your application to crash in the future.